# knockout validation IE 10

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a simple form with submit button. Submit button is enabled/disabled based on weather there are client side validation errors. I use following to see if there are any errors.

```
 validationModel.errors().length
```

For IE9, Chrome, and Safari this returns 0. However for IE10 this returns 1.

anyone knows why? and how to fix this?

Also, how do I see which field is throwing error?

Comment: Have you checked what is that one error? How is your viewModel look like? How is your validation set up?

Comment: Yes, it's a required field validation. Is there anyway for me to see what field that error is for?